# Create new file using JNDI

Tags: file, jndi

I am trying to use JNDI to create a new binding while using 'RefFSContextFactory'. So what i am trying to do create a new File using JNDI. However this code throws an exception javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Can only bind References or Referenceable objects.

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
public class Main2 {

  public static void main(String [] rgstring) throws IOException {
    try {
      Hashtable<String,String> hashtableEnvironment = new Hashtable<String,String>();
      hashtableEnvironment.put(
        Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
        "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"
      );
      hashtableEnvironment.put(
        Context.PROVIDER_URL, 
        "file:///TestingApps/"
      );
      Context context = new InitialContext(hashtableEnvironment);

      //File f=new File("C:\\TestingApps\\test");
      //f.createNewFile();
      context.bind("test", null);
      context.close();
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Is this possible using JNDI? Should the bound object be an object of File and cannot be null?

Answer (score 0):

> So what i am trying to do create a new
>   File using JNDI.

(a) Why? f.createNewFile() does that.

(b) You can't.

(c) That's not what JNDI is for, or the file-system provider either. It is for recording bindings *in* a file, or files.

As you were also told [on the Oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9576242#9576242).